# laravel query нужно сделать запрос на выборку вакансий с периодами

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Вообщем есть запрос:

```
DB::table('vacancies')
                ->leftJoin('periods', 'vacancies.id', '=', 'periods.id_vacancy')
                ->select('vacancies.title_u', 'periods.date_start', 'periods.date_end')
                ->take(1)->get();
```

Результат:

```
array:1 [▼
  0 => {#389 ▼
    +"title_u": "Водитель"
    +"date_start": 1469680740
    +"date_end": 1469939940
  }
]
```

Нужно сделать запрос, что бы у вакансий было несколько периодов в массиве (то что ниже), Как это можно сделать?

```
array:1 [▼
  0 => array:2 [▼
    "title_u" => "Водитель"
    "periods" => array:2 [▼
      "date_start" => 1469680740
      "date_end" => 1469939940
    ]
  ]
]
```

Comment: А как пытались сделать это вы? Пробовали ли сформировать руками нужный массив?

Comment: Да)) намудрил конечно

Comment: Покажите, как пробовали, прямо в вопросе

Comment: т.е. не пробовал, не знаю как сформулировать запрос